# How do I view files as a tree structure?

Tags: command-line

I would like to view files exactly like I can view proccess using `pstree`.

So is there something like:

```
treeview --maxdepth 2
```

that would give me what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tree utility for this:

```
tree -L 2
```